# NFSv4 fsid Option And The Purpose Of Export Roots

Tags: nfs4

My file server just has one big partition sharing stuff out under /exports. So using  the old style NFSv3 exports I had:

```
/exports/home     192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/exports/root     192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

So I decided to switch to the NFSv4 style and changed it to:

```
/exports          192.168.1.0/24(ro,fsid=0,no_subtree_check)
/exports/home     192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/exports/root     192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
#/etc              192.168.1.0/24(ro,no_subtree_check) # Test entry to check export root is working.
```

I then changed the mount commands to exclude `/exports`. Sure enough `/etc` was unmountable (although it didn't error, it just locked until interrupted). However, as I expected, `/exports`'s ACLs were still inherited downwards, all shares were read-only and root was squashed everywhere.

I also tried changing the ACL for `/exports/root` to a single machine but it made no difference.

So beyond being able to provide a unique identifier for those filesystems where such an identifier can't be determined, what is the point of defining an export root with `fsid=0`:

- Doing so reduces flexibility in terms of how shares get set up (i.e. the inheritance issue, unless on different filesystems and you use `nocrossmount`?).
- Assuming the old style NFSv3 setup, you still can't mount `/etc` so what extra security does it provide?

Does `fsid=0` only make sense when `/exports` is just a mounting area for separate file systems that get mounted in there and exported with different acls?

It seems to me that the setup of NFS servers has been flipped around. Back in the day on Solaris, you'd have all shared stuff directly mounted under `/export` and shared out. The server would have `/home/user` bind mounted to `/export/home/user`. But now `/home` is the real filesystem mount location and is bind mounted under `/exports`.

Is this correct?

**Please Note**: The above examples are for illustrative purposes only so please no comments about the wisdom of not using `no_squash_root`, I know.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's an architectural change in how the NFS "mount" protocol works.

In NFSv2/v3 there was an entirely separate 'MOUNT' RPC protocol which allowed the client to get a filehandle of any exported filesystem by its path. But in the subsequent WebNFS – and later in NFSv4 – mounting was changed to an in-band NFS operation, and at the same time the operation was changed to return a single "root" filehandle from which all path lookups then descend. (Actually WebNFS had two such roots, another being a "public" root for nfs:// URLs, which didn't make it to NFSv4.)

So in order for the 'PUTROOTFH' operation to work, there must *be* a root filesystem of some kind, as it is not possible to skip the steps anymore – all path traversals are a series of [PUTROOTFH, LOOKUP, LOOKUP, ..., LOOKUP, OPEN] compound operations. This mirrors Plan9's 9p as well as SMBv2/3.

(All of this implies that in this style, the exported filesystem paths become relative to the root, e.g. your /exports/home is mounted as "foo:/home", *not* as "foo:/exports/home".)

The lack of a MOUNT(path) operation is also what makes "crossmnt" implied as there *isn't* anything left to mount anymore, it's all just 'LOOKUP' down from the root.

In practice, NFSv4 can use either style – if a "fsid=0" export is not defined, the Linux kernel (2.6.33 or later) **will automatically generate a virtual `/` root for you** that contains nothing except mounts for your regular exported locations. (This also has the advantage of retaining identical mount paths between NFSv3 and NFSv4.) In other words, you can really continue using your original v3-style configuration.

Comment: Many thanks for your full and clear answer :-). It now makes sense.